# Weird error with .presentScene / Swift 3 (SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am getting a weird error with this code. So basically I am trying to transition scenes and I've typed the code and have looked over Apple's documentation multiple times. But cannot seem to figure this error out. Any help is appreciated. I am just trying to make a simple transition from Scene 1 to 2. I'm super irritated because I've searched so many places and cannot find the answer to this question. Thanks a ton.

As of right now, I have TWO scenes: The first one being "FirstScene" and the second one being "GameScene". I'm trying to transition from Scene 1(First Scene) to Scene 2(GameScene).

> Error I'm getting: "Cannot convert value of type '(fileNamed: String)' to specified type 'SKScene!'"

```
let yourNextScene:SKScene! = (fileNamed: "GameScene")
let transition = SKTransition.moveIn(with: .right, duration: 1)
scene?.view?.presentScene(yourNextScene as SKScene, transition: transition)
```

Comment: let yourNextScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")

Comment: It worked! Thank you Sir!

Comment: Using : just specifies the type-- it doesn't automatically call the initializer .. This is basically just `SKScene.init(fileNamed: "GameScene")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let yourNextScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

Using `:` just specifies the type-- it doesn't automatically call the initializer .. This is basically just `SKScene.init(fileNamed: "GameScene")`

You could also do the verbose way:

`let urnextscene: SKScene = SKScene(yaadayada)`

Command click on SKScene and you will see the initializer in the SpriteKit.h file.

Comment: [command + alt] plus click opens `SpriteKit.h` in assistant editor, so you don't lose your place. If you do jump, go back real quick with [control + command + leftArrow]